# How to allow user to create two instances of a jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I have created following plugin. When I try to initialize it twice it does not work. In the demo if you open your browser console the `open` link is not responding. Instead the menu links are calling the `secondFunc` function twice . I don't understand where I have done a mistake.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="home">
       <div class="open-door-c">
           <a href="#" class="open-door">open</a>
        </div>
        <div class="container"> 
            <div class="info" >
                <div class="nav">
                    <ul class="menu">
                        <li><a href="#" class="link">1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="link">2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="link">3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="link">4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="link">5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="more-details-container">
                    <div>
                        <h1>title</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sec">
                        1
                    </div>
                    <div class="sec">
                        2
                    </div>
                    <div class="sec">
                        3
                    </div>
                    <div class="sec">
                        4
                    </div>
                    <div class="sec">
                        5
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Plugin**

```
 (function ($, window, document, undefind) { 
   var MyPlugin = {    
    init : function (options, element) { 
        $.extend({}, $.fn.myPlugin.options, options);            
        $.fn.myPlugin.options.linkClass.on('click', this.secondFunc);
    },

    secondFunc : function () {
        alert(this);
    }

}; 

$.fn.myPlugin = function (options) {  
    return this.each(function (options) {
        var rezG = Object.create(MyPlugin);
        rezG.init(options, this);
    });        
};

$.fn.myPlugin.options = {
    linkClass: $('.link')       
};

})(jQuery, window, document);

$('.more-details-container').myPlugin({
            linkClass: $('.link')
        });
        $('.home').myPlugin({
            linkClass: $('.open-door')
        });
```

**[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XA2BL/2/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible *mistakes*:

- `$.extend({}, $.fn.myPlugin.options, options);` will just return a new object containing properties of both $.fn.myPlugin.options and options, but it won't update your $.fn.myPlugin.options object which you're using below:

  $.fn.myPlugin.options.linkClass.on('click', this.secondFunc);

To keep both the original objects and assign the extended object to your $.fn.myPlugin.options, try this instead:

```
$.fn.myPlugin.options = $.extend({}, $.fn.myPlugin.options, options); // read more on [jQuery extend](// http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/)
```

- I think there is no need to use each iteration below:

`$.fn.myPlugin = function(options) {
        return this.each(function(options) {
            var rezG = Object.create(MyPlugin);
            rezG.init(options, this);
        });
    };`

`init()` will be called right when you're instantiating a new plugin with `element.myPlugin(...);`, which will create a new plugin reference with the specified argument `options`.

Have a look at this updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XA2BL/5/) and see if that's you're looking for.